# Setter method is odd, can someone explain

Tags: objective-c, getter-setter

I'm taking a look at the developer library for iOS. A property called `masterBirdSightingList` was created with type `NSMutableArray`.Thats fine, in the implementation they added this peice of code

```
- (void)setMasterBirdSightingList:(NSMutableArray *)newList {
    if (_masterBirdSightingList != newList) {
        _masterBirdSightingList = [newList mutableCopy];
    }
}
```

In order to

> To implement a custom setter for the master list property ... (and) to override its default setter method to make sure that the new array remains mutable.

I'm not quite sure why this is fully necessary. Surely the array cannot suddenly change from a mutable array to something static. Is this method necessary?

Could you also help clarify whether the method `setMasterBirdSightingList` is called every time the `masterBirdSightingList` is set?

The tutorial I'm talking about is [available here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SecondiOSAppTutorial/DesigningDataModel/DesigningDataModel.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011318-CH3-SW2) about halfway down the page.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Could you also help clarify whether the method `setMasterBirdSightingList` is called every time the `masterBirdSightingList` is set?

Yes, it is - in Objective-C, property access is implemented using getter and setter methods. No exception. The dot notation is just syntactic sugar for `- (T)foo` and `- (void)setFoo:(T)arg`.

> I'm not quite sure why this is fully necessary.

Because if you just declared a `copy` property, then upon setting the array, it would be sent the `copy` message, and that returns an **immutable** copy (in Cocoa [Touch], it's a common convention that `copy` returns an immutable copy, even if the original object was mutable.)

This is why explicitly sending `mutableCopy` to the argument is needed.